# What is the best way to cache a home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple home page, like that:

index view with partials:

- header
- how_it_works
- benefits
- customer_supports
- about
- covered_areas

I tried to use "Page Caching"/"Action Caching". But in my layout I have a top header that has a condition `if user_signed_in?`. So using "Page Caching"/"Action Caching" doesn't work for me.

Should I use "Fragment Caching" for each partial?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `caches_action :index, layout: false` if the problem is only about the layout.